# Will Visual Studio 2013 marry it's current product key to my account if I sign-in?

Tags: product-key, visual-studio-2013, microsoft-account

I just recently switch from using Visual Studio 2010 to Visual Studio 2013 at work. Visual Studio 2013 is registered with an MSDN product key that the company pays for. I am new to the concept of using a Microsoft account to sign-in to Visual Studio to sync settings and more across devices. I would like to use my Microsoft account for that purpose here at work but have a concern. I am unsure if signing in to Visual Studio 2013 will marry the Company's product key to my account. I, personally, do not have an MSDN subscription on my account (if that even matters). I just want to be able to sync my settings between PCs at work without having to worry about that. Unfortunately my Google-Fu has failed me in helping me figure this out. I'm hoping someone here knows the answer to this riddle.

Answer (score -1):

Of course, you can ask Microsoft directly to find out for sure, but AFAIK, it will not link the key to your account.
I use VS 2013 like this all the time.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I was hoping for a little more concrete evidence. Can you provide any?

Comment: Microsoft is the best and trustable source in this case.

Answer (score -1):

I feel I have found the concrete evidence I was searching for. I stumbled upon (no pun intended) Jeff Bramwell's blog post **Visual Studio 2013 Settings Sync & Licensing**. From what I understood, there are two forms of licensing the product. Either sign-in with an MSDN account that is licensed for Visual Studio 2013 or license the product directly with a product key, then you are able to sign-in with whatever Microsoft account you desire. He tested with two MSDN subscription accounts and one account without an MSDN subscription and screenshot each scenario. Here is the link to his post: http://blog.devmatter.com/visual-studio-2013-settings-sync-licensing/